# Calling async Web API method from App.OnStartup

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I changed App.OnStartup to be async so that I can call an async method on a web api, but now my app does not show its window. What am I doing wrong here:

```
    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await TestWebAPI();
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The service is currently unavailable"); 
            Shutdown(1);
        }

        this.StartupUri = new Uri("MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> TestWebAPI()
    {
        using (var webClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
        {
            webClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiAddress"]);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await webClient.GetAsync("api/hello", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

If I take out the async call to TestWebAPI it shows fine.

Comment: The way you have coded this means that your message box and or MainWindow.xaml will not appear until your asynchronous method completes.  The `await` keyword makes all subsequent lines of code a continuation that will be executed when the task completes.  If you explain more what you are *trying* to do, someone can help you better.

Comment: Just trying to not show my main window if I don't need to. So if the web service is down, notify the user and close.  In this case, the web service is alive but I see no main window.

Comment: I can make it all synchronous by calling .Result on the GetAsync method, but would I be losing any benefit here from that?

Comment: Your code is executing sequentially and asynchronously (i.e. TestWebAPI is asynchronous but the test of `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` and everything after it is executed sequentially from `TestWebAPI`).  You want your asynchronous method to execute "in the background" in relation to the code that follows it--which means not using `await`.  I would recommended adding the "Async" suffice to the method to it's is more clear that calling that method does something asynchronously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that WPF expects `StartupUri` to be set *before* `OnStartup` returns. So, I'd try creating the window explicitly in the `Startup` event:

```
private async void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  HttpResponseMessage response = await TestWebAPIAsync();
  if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("The service is currently unavailable"); 
    Shutdown(1);
  }
  MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
  main.DataContext = ...
  main.Show();
}
```

Comment: This fixed it just fine.  A related question: what does async bring me here?  It's not as if I need the UI thread to be doing anything while I'm checking my web service because I want to shutdown without even showing the UI if the service is not available...

Comment: It doesn't gain you anything in this case. If you were, say, showing a splash screen that could be moved/minimized (which is not a bad idea), then it would allow that splash screen to be responsive.

Answer (score -1):

**Did you try this?**

```
this.OnStartup += async (s, e) =>
   {
     ...
   };
```

**Or**

```
this.Loaded += async (s, e) =>
   {
     ...
   };
```

Or you can pick another event that's related.

Comment: Don't follow what that would do.  But it looks like my code was fine, just WPF handles showing the main window in it's own way, so making the change suggested by Stephen worked.