# System.Environment.Exit(0) preventing hockeyapp from registering a crash

Tags: c#, wpf, crash-reports, hockeyapp

I started a blank WPF application (shown below) to implement HockeyApp crash reporting. When the program starts, a window popups up with a single button for the user to press. When the user clicks it the handler attempts to divide by zero and crashes the app. I was receiving crash reports and everything was running smoothly UNTIL I mimicked our bigger system's error catching method, which was to use the [DispatcherUnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) Event Handler to catch "uncaught" exceptions and then call [System.Environment.Exit(0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) to gracefully end anything in the background. Now the HockeyApp api isn't sending crash reports. I'm wondering if catching the exceptions at a higher level makes HockeyApp think "Oh, they got things under control" and won't register a "crash."

I'm currently talking to the HockeyApp support staff about this, but I'm wondering if anyone else has had this problem. Should I take out the Exit(0) line, or is there a better practice for exiting an app when we have an uncaught exception? I've tried changing the error code from 0 to 574 (ERROR_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION) with no result. I don't believe there's any data that we need to save, other than what the HockeyApp api already has.

App class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        RegisterHockeyAppCrashReporting();

        Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;
    }

    private void Current_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private async void RegisterHockeyAppCrashReporting()
    {
        HockeyClient.Current.Configure(AppConstants.APP_ID)
            .SetContactInfo(AppConstants.USER_NAME, AppConstants.USER_EMAIL);
        await HockeyClient.Current.SendCrashesAsync(true);
    }
}
```

MainWindow class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var zero = 0;
        var number = 1;
        var crash = number / zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you just remove the line that returns 0?

Comment: `async void RegisterHockeyAppCrashReporting()` that's a very serious bug. `async void` is only meant for *event handlers*. It can't be awaited Your application may terminate before the registration even runs. It may be what's causing the unhandled exception in the first place. Use `async Task` and *await* it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's a bug but it's a bit more complex in this example imho. `async void` was _probably_ meant to offload part of the event handler into the async context without making `OnLaunched` itself an async handler. A better way was to use something like `var task = RegisterFromTheCurrentUniqueContextButAwaitFromThreadPoolAsync(); task.Wait()`.

Comment: That would *block* immediatelly instead of awaiting. That's worse. The application startup event handler is exactly where `async void` should be used. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968015/calling-async-web-api-method-from-app-onstartup)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The app was actually running fine, but I'm glad you pointed that out. I totally forgot to change this code back to match the example on the [HockeyApp Github](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-WindowsDemo/blob/master/WindowsWPF/HockeyAppDemo/App.xaml.cs) example app. I was trying a slew of things to get it to work before discovering the exit code problem.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov I was trying to prevent OnLaunched from becoming async. For some reason the example code on the HockeyApp website does that and I thought it would break something. The call is now in a task/wait delegate and everything is working well.

Comment: @BrooksLindsey Glad to hear this )

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not really. If you register from the current context and await it's explicitly asynchronous continuation in the thread pool, you can block to wait for it without deadlock. Application startup is one of the places where you often need to block because you need for some initialization tasks to complete before OnLaunched handler returns (ofc it depends on what initialization you need and what OnLaunched() even does your platform provide). And, I guess, it would be this way until MS finally provides us with native implementation of `async` events (and native to OS `async` main).

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov that's not "not really". We aren't talking about deadlock, we are talking about *blocking*. And you *won't* lose anything if you make the event handler asynchronous in order to call the method properly. As for async events and main - you already have them. `async void` for events, `async Task Main()` in C# 7.1. You can use `async void` with the Startup **event** already. Check [Calling async Web API method from App.OnStartup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968015/calling-async-web-api-method-from-app-onstartup)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos event invoked with `async void` handlers will possibly return before the handlers finish their job, which can (as I mentioned) be the undesirable scenario, because you're initializing synchronous OS objects, loggers, injectors or anything else that _must_ be initialized _before_ you do anything else. So it should (if needed) run asynchronously but then be blocked.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yet again, not really. Event invoke should be `async`, not the handlers and for real `async Task Main()` which is syntactic sugar, the OS should allow native cross-process thread scheduling and allow processes with zero threads in it. Which won't happen. Anyway I guess that SO comments are not the best place for such discussions ^-^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Environement.Exit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) terminates your application *immediately*. So, I guess, there's nothing strange in the fact that Hockey does not do anything.

> Exit terminates an application immediately, even if other threads are
>   running. If the return statement is called in the application entry
>   point, it causes an application to terminate only after all foreground
>   threads have terminated.
>
> If Exit is called from a try or catch block, the code in any finally
>   block does not execute. If the return statement is used, the code in
>   the finally block does execute.

Best practices tend to be opinion based and situation dependent. We, for example, log stack trace on unhandled exceptions and then call `Environement.FailFast` in our UWP app (we do not use Hockey apps though). Our logic is simple - our logger facility is probably alive but we're not so sure about the rest of the app. If even the logger facility is not functional than we won't be able to do anything anyway. Imho `Exit` and `FailFast` are the last steps that should only be used when you have no hope of restoring some valid state.

Comment: Looks like I didn't fully understand the HockeyApp API. Their team also got back to me and said "This is likely because you are not allowing enough time for the SDK to save the exception by exiting your app immediately. Please note we do not directly support handled exceptions, however our product group is planning on releasing this in Mobile Center which is the next generation of HockeyApp."